# "Migrations" ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment parameters.)

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I've been trying to implement a DApp to the mainnet of ethereum and I keep running into this problem :

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'mainnet'
> Network id:      1
> Block gas limit: 30000000 (0x1c9c380)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment parameters.)
   * Block limit:  30000000 (0x1c9c380)
   * Gas sent:     139190886 (0x84be266)

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:364:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:68:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:55:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:171:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:79:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:269:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:231:1
Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Node v16.13.2
```

We have loaded over a $1000 eth in the deploying contract. Is there any way I could calculate the gas needed because it's becoming quite expensive?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

These are annoying bugs that often don't have a clear answer.

Few Things you can check:

1. In truffle config js, what is your gas limit ? try increasing that.
2. Other than that, there is a `--dry-run` flag in truffle deploy, which gives more detailed errors.
3. Do you have any loops in any constructors ? that might be eating up the gas limit